# How do I install a Rubbermaid closet organizer in a paneled mobile home?

Tags: walls, closet

I have a Rubbermaid Configurations closet organizer and have no confidence in the enclosed hardware. I have a mobile home and the walls are all paneled - the studs very difficult to find as well as being smaller than 2x4.

What type anchor screws should I use? Should I use furring strips?

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't trust the hardware either for mounting to a trailer wall unless they were standard drywall. Your idea of furring strips sounds good. Just screw them through the wall into the studs and you should be okay. You could get oak 1x2s for the furring strips and either stain them or paint them and they would be really solid to screw the organizer pieces to; but, if your're painting them, pine would work fine too.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to attach a finished piece of plywood over whole wall.
Hollow Wall anchors work best on thin paneling. I like toggle bolts except for the fact they make a big hole in wall.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy a couple of 1x2/3s (whatever you think looks nicer) and attach them vertically on the wall with wood glue (use some duct tape to hold it down while drying).  Then screw and install into those.